# Automatic query firing for sending mail

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-mail

I am developing an application(Employee exit process from a company) where a employee requesting for exit and his request would be forwarded to his primary supervisor for approval(We have a table in database where we have respective details about candidates like
employee->primary supervisor->HR Manager. So the supervisor will get an email to approve or reject the request. so depending on the reply of that mail we have to forward the request to HR for further approval or to inform the employee through mail that his request is rejected(the condition is all this should be processed automattically)..

Is there any solution that you can suggest ???

Comment: Can you please elaborate specifically what you are looking for? Because the title of your question and description is contradictory

Comment: For your requirements, should look into [BPMN](http://www.bpmn.org/) based frameworks (e.g Jboss's [JBPM](http://jbpm.jboss.org/), Oracle's [BPM](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/bpm/overview/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the aim is to develop the described system and the question is about its general architecture.

I'll try to give a couple of tips, hopefully they would help.

The primary indicator of the primary supervisor response is its e-mail reply? If its so, I think its not a good approach.

I wouldn't reply on e-mails for managing a "protocol" which is, essentially a part of the business logic of your application.

Using e-mail is totally fine to "notify" the supervisor that the employee wants to quit.

Now, as for me, you should build a server based application what will run in some container (you mention java), so take a look on tomcat, jetty and so forth.
This application will have the following logic:
The employee that wishes to quit, opens the application and gets to the screen "Report my will to quit" (I omit credentials and everything for brevity) with a button "Report".
Now, when the employee hits the report button, the system should find out who is the direct supervisor of that employee, *generate* an e-mail to  him/her and send.

Now, this mail is a notification it should contain the information like this:
 - Employee "John Johnson" has reported that he wants to quit. Please check the *now the link should come*. The link leads to the aforementioned system (with parameters and everything). The Supervisor now gets to the special screen where he/she has an option to agree (a button) or to disagree (another button).
If the supervisor agrees, the system generated an e-mail to HR and to the employee.

General notes:
Pay attention, everything is done within the system, the e-mail is used only as a notification mechanism.

In addition to this fairly basic functionality the system should "memorize" the state of the whole process. The states should be like "employee X has asked to quit", "the supervisor agreed" and so forth.

The system is independent of the e-mails (If e-mails go offline or something your system will still work). Moreover sometimes the supervisor just wants to enter the system and see what happens there without even opening the e-mail. The same holds for HR.

Of course this explanation is fairly basic, but I guess you've got the idea.

Hope this helps